# why this JavaScript method return undefined?

Tags: javascript

in this code this method return undefined despites alert statement print a value ?

```
function getNearestPoint(idd) 
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            var result;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            else
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");     
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        result= xmlhttp.responseText;
                        alert(result);

                    }

            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_get_nearest_location.php?id="+idd +"&radius=1",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Because your function returns before a result is returned from the AJAX request. The request is Asynchronous.

Comment: I'm afraid people will never stop asking this kind of questions.... :-/ We have to start some campaign.

Comment: @Felix we need a reference question that we all can link to (or close as a duplicate of) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

result isn't defined at that point, it only gets defined once your callback executes.  The order of execution:

- `getNearestPoint` starts
- XHR is fired off
- `getNearestPoint` returns `undefiend`
- XHR comes back and runs `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`
- result gets set

If you need result from OUTSIDE of this, you should use a callback:

```
getNearestPoint(idd, cb){
   ...
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      ...
      cb(result);
   }
}
```

and your calling code changes from:

```
var result = getNearestPoint(id);
```

to:

```
getNearestPoint(id, function(result){
   // do something with result;
});
```

Comment: i want to call it like this way ?   var url="getShortestPath.php?from="+getNearestPoint(id1)+"&to="+getNearestPoint(id2);
 how can i do that ?

Comment: @adham: That is not possible with asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the asychronous nature of Ajax ("Asynchronous JavaScript and XML"): The request will still be running when your code hits `return result`. The readystatechange callback will not have been called yet, and the `result` variable not set yet.

The usual way to deal with this is to change the architecture of the script: Do whatever you need to do based on `result` directly in the `onreadystatechange` callback. (or, of course, pass a callback function with the desired actions and execute it in the handler.)

Comment: The only downside to running code directly in `onreadystatechange` is that it kills re-usability of the code.  Better, in general, to use a callback

Answer (score 0):

### `result` setting statement executes inside async Ajax function

Because your second `if` statement (that sets `result` value) doesn't get hit. Why not? Because the moment you send an Ajax request you return the `result` value which is still undefined. Ajax call will execute the anonymous function later on and set this `result` variable which has been returned long ago.

### Ajax is asynchronous and your code isn't taking this into account.