# Can't access data in JSON format after REST call

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I have accessed a web service that delivers data back as a JSON object.  From what I understand, the JSON has already been parsed, so I should be able to simply access the data.  But every time I try, I keep getting back undefined.

This is the code:

```
xhr.open("GET", requestString, true);
xhr.send();

myThing = xhr.response.cod;
console.log(myThing)
```

And this is the request:

[image]

Anything I true seems to return "undefined".  After searching, I found that the result should already be parsed to JSON and I should just be able to access it as such.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why this JavaScript method return undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656490/why-this-javascript-method-return-undefined)

Comment: If your code is like that then the problem happens because you're asking for an async request and not handling it in an async callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to async your code needs to be structured thusly, [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/server', true);

xhr.onload = function () {
  // Request finished. Do processing here.
  var data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
  console.log(data.cod);
};

xhr.send(null);
// any kind of "return" or operation down here that expects xhr.response to exist will *FAIL*
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was able to get it to print the results to console by logging `xhr.responseText`, but when I try to save it to a variable, and then print that variable after the result is opened and `xhr.send(null)` is sent, I still get undefined.  Can `responseText` simply not be saved by itself to a variable?

Comment: Sure, just make sure you do that inside the onload function.  But you won't be able to return it, nor will your other code know when it will be available.  Usually it's best to do all operations on an ajax response within the callback.

Comment: So, how do you pick out data from the returned JSON inside the onload function? I am trying to retried simple elements like `xhr.response.cod` for instance but it is still returning undefined...

Comment: It's been a while since I used a "naked" xhr object (usually jQuery) so I hope that my edits are valid, please give that a go.

Comment: Oh, snap.  I get it now.  I have to use `JSON.parse` on `xhr.responseText`, inside the `onload` function and THEN I can access it like a JSON object.